# Использование новшеств .NET

Tags: c#, .net

В платформу .NET часто добавляются новые технологии, методы, классы (и т.д.) для использования их из различных языков программирования (пускай, в данном случае это будет C# ). Собственно, вопрос такой: что, если есть некое C#-приложение, использующее функционал, например, версии фреймворка 4.5+ и запущенное на компьютере, где установлена версия порядком ниже (например, 2.0 ). Как в таком случае отреагирует виртуальная машина .NET, встретив неизвестные для себя IL вызовы и конструкции? Да и запустится ли приложении вообще?

Comment: Если я правильно помню, то оно сообщит о том, что нужна более новая версия .NET'a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я сильно сомневаюсь, что набор IL-инструкций очень изменяется (и что вообще изменяется) от одной версии .NET к другой. Однако сброки, входящие в .NET, и их содержимое, разумеется, меняются. При создании приложения вы явно указываете (даже если не подозреваете об этом), под какими версиями .NET оно будет работать. Если на машине нет ни одной из этих версий, то ваше приложение просто не запустится.

Comment: Хм, точно, ведь даже в том же Visual Studio в настройках проекта всегда указыватеся target-версия .NET. Спасибо, теперь все стало на свои места.